# True content is not copied from one QMap into another QMap

Tags: c++, qt5

When I press the close button on the tab widget, that tab must close, and the corresponding member of the `identifyedWidgetMap` must be copied into the `deletedWidgetMap`. However, the copying does not happen.

For instance, I close `Tab_3` but there is in the `deletedWidgetMap` some information: `4, QWidget(0x17424a1)`.

Help if you can. Thank you.

That code lines I created are located below.

## Header

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QAction>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QMap>
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QFont>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void setMainWindowPropertiesAndItems();
    QMenuBar* menuBar;
    QMenu* fileMenu;
    QAction* newTabAction;
    QAction* openAction;
    QTabWidget* tabWidget;
    QMap<int, QWidget*> identifyedWidgetMap;
    QMap<int, QWidget*> deletedWidgetMap;
    QList<QTextEdit*> textEditList;
    QVBoxLayout* vBoxLayout;

private slots:
    void newTabActionHandler();
    void openActionHandler();
    void tryingToCloseConcreteTab(int);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

## Source

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setMainWindowPropertiesAndItems();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::setMainWindowPropertiesAndItems()
{
    setWindowTitle("Notepad");
    setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 250);
    move(270, 270);

    menuBar = new QMenuBar(this);
    setMenuBar(menuBar);

    fileMenu = new QMenu("&File", this);
    menuBar->addMenu(fileMenu);

    newTabAction = new QAction("&New Tab", this);
    fileMenu->addAction(newTabAction);
    connect(newTabAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this,    
        SLOT(newTabActionCommandsHandler()));

    openAction = new QAction("&Open", this);
    fileMenu->addAction(openAction);
    connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, 
        SLOT(openActionCommandsHandler()));

    identifyedWidgetMap.insert(0, new QWidget(this));
    textEditList.append(new QTextEdit(this));
    tabWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
    tabWidget->addTab(identifyedWidgetMap.value(0), QString("Tab 
        %1").arg(identifyedWidgetMap.size()-1));
    tabWidget->setMovable(true);
    tabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);
    connect(tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabCloseRequested(int)), this, 
        SLOT(tryingToCloseConcreteTab(int)));
    vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    identifyedWidgetMap.value(0)->setLayout(vBoxLayout);
    vBoxLayout->addWidget(textEditList[0]);
    textEditList[0]->setCurrentFont(QFont("Monospace Regular", 14));
    setCentralWidget(tabWidget);
}

void MainWindow::newTabActionCommandsHandler()
{
    if(bool(deletedWidgetMap.isEmpty()) == true)
    {
        identifyedWidgetMap.insert(identifyedWidgetMap.size(), new 
            QWidget(this));
        textEditList.append(new QTextEdit(this));
        tabWidget->           
        addTab(identifyedWidgetMap.value(identifyedWidgetMap.size()-1), 
        QString("Tab %1").arg(identifyedWidgetMap.size()-1));
        tabWidget-> 
        setCurrentWidget(identifyedWidgetMap.
        value(identifyedWidgetMap.size()-1));
        vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        identifyedWidgetMap.value(identifyedWidgetMap.size()-1)->
        setLayout(vBoxLayout);
        vBoxLayout->addWidget(textEditList[textEditList.size()-1]);
        textEditList[textEditList.size()-1]->setCurrentFont(QFont("Monospace 
        Regular", 14));
    }
}

void MainWindow::openActionCommandsHandler()
{
    QWidget* currentWidget = tabWidget->currentWidget();
    std::cout<<"The currentWidget address is: "<<currentWidget<<std::endl;

    qDebug()<<"The complete identifyedWidgetMap address set is: ";
    foreach(int widgetIdentifyer, identifyedWidgetMap.keys())
    {
        qDebug()<<widgetIdentifyer<<", "
        <<identifyedWidgetMap.value(widgetIdentifyer);
    }

    int currentWidgetIndex = 0;
    currentWidgetIndex = tabWidget->currentIndex();
    std::cout<<"The currentWidgetIndex is: "<<currentWidgetIndex<<std::endl;

    qDebug()<<"The complete deletedWidgetMap set is: ";
    foreach(int widgetIdentifyer, deletedWidgetMap.keys())
    {
        qDebug()<<widgetIdentifyer<<", " 
        <<deletedWidgetMap.value(widgetIdentifyer);
    }
}

void MainWindow::tryingToCloseConcreteTab(int concreteIndex)
{
    tabWidget->removeTab(concreteIndex);
    std::cout<<"Deleted identifyer is: "<<concreteIndex<<std::endl;
    deletedWidgetMap.insert(identifyedWidgetMap.key(tabWidget- 
    >widget(concreteIndex)), 
    identifyedWidgetMap.value(identifyedWidgetMap.key(tabWidget- 
    >widget(concreteIndex))));
}
```

Comment: Do some research about *deep copying*. And think about if you really need it.

Comment: Perhaps `tabWidget->removeTab(concreteIndex);` is your problem. Should you get the pointer to the widget before removing it? I don't think  `tabWidget->widget(concreteIndex)` will return the correct pointer after the tab is gone.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, You know even considering high reputation which you have I think you are wrong in providing right answer on this question. Although perhaps your idea has right to live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is you first remove the tab from the tabWidget. This results in an index change, the next tab will shift to left when you remove the tab. When you try to access the tab with `tabWidget->widget(concreteIndex)`you access the next tab.

You may consider adding tab to the `deletedWidgetMap` before removing it.

Comment: I have tryed as you have said and this method is right. But I have one question to you. Why will the next tab shift to left when I remove the tab?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov, Assume there are 4 elements in a list. If you remove the 2nd item, the 3rd item would be the 2nd after removal.

Comment: It is logical. Thank you for the right provided answer. And therefore this theme may be considered as solved.